# Custom content (checkbox) in FullCalendar in AgendaWeek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar plugin in AgendaWeek view.
I'd like to show a checkbox in each cell, even the empty ones.
I looked through all the documentation, but I couldn't find anything that could help me.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect you'd have to modify the source code, in the part where it renders the grid of the view. There's no real option for that I don't think. You could try via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender but not sure exactly what `cell` contains when the view is agenda style, because clearly there's more than one cell. If it's a wrapper for all the timeslot cells, you might be in luck, but I suspect it won't be. Anyway what's the purpose of the checkbox? Perhaps there is in fact a better way to achieve your actual goal, if you explain your requirement.

Comment: dayRender gets you the "all-day" slot at the top for agenda view. You could find all slots in viewRender method and insert checkbox. **$('div.fc-slats td.fc-widget-content').not('.fc-axis'); // finds all agenda slots, except the "all-day" at the top**

Comment: Hi, @smcd great answer, but I need something that applies to every cell, not the full row.

Comment: @ADyson, I need people to open the calendar and click on a slot. That slot becomes then available (read: it changes its colour). It works fine with the select method, but I'd like to add a checkbox so it could be more helpful for the final user.

Comment: Well if you can get something working with the `select` callback, then you just have to weigh up whether doing what I outlined is worth the effort and time, compared to having something which works, but isn't quite what you envisaged. So it's a judgement call for you, I guess